# Simulating for the purpose of supply protection diodes

Tags: ltspice

[image: Block diagram]

I'm having trouble with making sense of and most importantly simulate a scenario about protection diodes used in series power supply operation. And the two reasons are given for their necessity are:

1. The diodes limit the current during a short circuit across the load.
2. The diodes also prevent possible reverse voltage damage if one power supply is off while the others are on.

I have come across three sources about it:

https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/blog_how-to-operate-parallel-and-series-connection.pdf

http://powersupply.blogs.keysight.com/2014/10/what-is-reverse-protection-diode-and.html

https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/can-you-recommend-a-diode-for-using-power-supply-in-series.140359/

I try to model and simulate the series operation with shorted load (1mOhm) for the first argument above as follows:

[image: Schematic]

But the diodes do not have any effect and zero current passes according to the above simulation model. So they don't protect anything in my model.

Can someone simulate these two arguments to show that they are correct?

**Edit:**

I still cannot get the expected output after adding series resistors for power supplies:

[image]

Diodes still dont conduct and do not protect anything.

Comment: Add a series resistor to one of the voltage sources, i.e. 1 Ohm, to simulate how its voltage drops under load.

Comment: Add inductance in series with your load and suddenly change one supply to 0 V.

Comment: These are protection devices. They are meant to ideally do absolutely nothing during regular operation.

Comment: See  my edit. Still doesnt work. I think I will open this for bounty.

Answer (score 1):

> But the diodes do not have any effect and zero current passes according to the above simulation model. So they don't protect anything in my model.

The diodes have zero effect on the operation of your model. It doesn't matter how big or a small the load is the diodes will always have 12V across them as a reverse bias. So they will pass zero current and the load will pass 24000A in your case.

If instead, a wire is placed where the load resistor is, the current becomes undefined. LTspice will ask you to correct the circuit before it will simulate.

A more realistic situation has the voltage sources perform some current limiting action. This can be active or passive, foldback or not. It doesn't really matter. Once in current limiting, the voltage sources turn into current sources, even if the limiting hardware is a simple resistor.

If both current limited supplies are identical, then the diodes still will not have any effect regardless of the load. The outer loop will take all of the current.

The next step is to consider real voltage sources. They are not identical. Under short circuit load conditions, \$V_{1}\$ becomes \$I_{1}\$ while \$V_{2}\$ becomes \$I_{1}\$. Both are now current sources. Furthermore \$I_{1}\ne I_{2}\$. Taking the case that \$I_{1}>I_{2}\$. KCL then requires \$I_{D2}=I_{1}-I_{2}\$.

> The diodes limit the current during a short circuit across the load.

**No!** Diodes do not limit current. In this case they allow the difference current to have a low resistance path to follow that occurs under short circuit conditions.

> The diodes also prevent possible reverse voltage damage if one power supply is off while the others are on.

**Yes!** If \$V_{1}\$ is off, then \$V_{2}\$'s current path will create a negative voltage across \$V_{1}\$, whether \$V_{2}\$ is in current limit or not. The diode across \$V_{1}\$ will allow a low resistance path from \$V_{2}\$ to the load and also keep the reverse voltage across \$V_{1}\$ to 0.7 volts.

This is easily simulated by placing equal 1 ohm resistors in series with each supply. There will still be no current in the diodes.

Make one resistor 1.5 ohms, then you will see current in one of the diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcukec.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: See my edit adding series resitot didnt have any effect on simulation. Diodes still dont conduct. And please simulate and add to your answer your results.

Comment: Read the last line in my answer. The edit in the question performs exactly as predicted in my answer. If the sources are identical, then there will be no current in either diode. Change one resistor to a different value will cause current in one diode. Please read and consider my entire answer.

Comment: @user1245, The simulation is added.